# fullCalendar will not render events from variable array

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have events formatted and in a variable named `events` as follows (3 events listed, each with `title`, `start` ,`end`)

```
[
  {title : 'workout',  start : '2018-01-02T15:00:00', end : '2018-01-02T16:00:00'},
  {title : 'workout3', start : '2018-01-04T15:30:00', end : '2018-01-04T16:30:00'},
  {title : 'workout',  start : '2018-01-03T1:30:00',  end : '2018-01-03T1:50:00'}
]
```

When I pass the `events` variable to the calendar using `events: events`, the events are not displayed.

In JavaScript, if I simply alert the variable `events` to the screen and copy/paste it into my code as the `events` variable, the events all appear in the calendar correctly.

Why would the same exact data in the same exact format not appear in the calendar? How can I get the data in the variable to render?

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  var events1 = []; 
  $('#caltable tbody>tr').each(function () { 
    table_row_data = []; 
    $('td', this).each(function () { 
      table_row_data.push($(this).text()); 
    }); 
    if (table_row_data.length > 0) { // Only add a row if it's not empty 
      events1.push("{"+table_row_data+"}"); 
    } 
  }); 
  var events = "["+events1+"]" 
  alert(events);
```

Comment: If you've got some code which isn't working, can you show it to us please? When you do `events: events`...where is your variable coming from originally? Is it definitely populated at the time the calendar runs? You haven't given us any code or explained what debugging you've done, and whether you get any errors, or at what point things start to go wrong, so it's difficult to give any more than the rather speculative help in Eleazar's answer.

Comment: I get the calendar information from a table and format it like this within the same JS as the calendar event: `$(document).ready(function() {

var events1 = [];
$('#caltable tbody>tr').each(function () {
    table_row_data = [];
    $('td', this).each(function () {
  table_row_data.push($(this).text());
    });
        if (table_row_data.length > 0) { // Only add a row if it's not empty
        events1.push("{"+table_row_data+"}");
    }
});

var events = "["+events1+"]"

alert(events);`  At the alert I can see data looks correctly formatted.I then use Eleazar's code below.

Comment: your problem is that `events` is a string, not an array. It _looks_ like an array when you view it, but it's not - you added the `[` and `]` as string characters. This is not how you create an array in Javascript. In fact I don't understand why you ever did this, because `events1` is already a an array. The other thing is that `"{"+table_row_data+"}"` in there is a string as well, not an object. Should I assume that `table_row_data` is a string which looks like `title : 'workout',  start : '2018-01-02T15:00:00', end : '2018-01-02T16:00:00'`? You need to make actual JS objects, not strings.

Comment: That was really insightful, thank you. Can you please point me in the right direction for creating the JS object from the data I have?  I am thinking, based on research, use JSON.stringify() to convert events1 to JSON string format and then parse the result using JSON.parse() to convert a json string to object.  Then pass that result to events in fullCalendar?  Would that sound correct?  I'm going to give that a shot ASAP unless you recommend something else.

Comment: "use JSON.stringify() to convert events1 to JSON string format". The problem with that is that it's already a string. You haven't got a proper object to stringify, which was my point. If you already had an object, there'd be no problem. Another issue you've got is that what's in the table isn't technically valid JSON and will be difficult to parse.

Comment: Why don't you just populate the calendar using the same source data as was used to populate the table instead of creating this convoluted dependency between two UI elements (table and calendar)? It's not like the data in the the table is presented in a very user-friendly way anyhow, so then you'd be free to format that more nicely, or even get rid of it. (In fact, if you decided to get rid of it or change its structure in future, as things stand you'd be stuck because of the calendar dependency, but if you de-couple them then you'll never have that issue).

Comment: I really appreciate your help, thank you, I think I'm getting closer - I pass the caldata from Python using: caldata=json.dumps(caldata). In JS `$(document).ready(function() {

 var data = jQuery.parseJSON('{{caldata | safe}}');

    var events;
    events = [];
    events.push(data);
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

theme: true, 
 events: events

});` No events appear, when I alert the content of events I get [object Object]  when I alert events.title I get undefined so I think my data is still not being formatted correctly but I am using JSON on both sides.

Comment: I also tried JSON.parse('{{caldata | safe}}'); in the JS and got the same [object Object] and undefined when using alert.  If I remove the |safe (which I didn't see in any documentation) if get:  JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data. Again I appreciate the help and patience.

Comment: `{{caldata | safe}}` I have no idea what this is or what it produces. Presumably it's syntax of some library you're using to build your HTML / Javascript? Either way, I guess that in turn refers to some source data. Are you using some server-side script? Normally they have functions (e.g. php's json_encode) to convert objects directly to JSON which you could inject directly into your calendar config, or provide the functionality as a separate URL endpoint to be called via ajax. Without seeing more context of your application it's difficult to advise specifically what to do.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have problems adding events after an async call.

Because initializing the `fullcalendar` works perfectly using the following:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({'events': [...]});
```

For async calls, you can attach the event [`addEventSource`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/addEventSource/) to add events programmatically.

**Take a look at this code snippet:**

```js
let myEvents = [{
    title: 'event1',
    start: '2018-01-01'
  },
  {
    title: 'event2',
    start: '2018-01-05',
    end: '2018-01-07'
  },
  {
    title: 'event3',
    start: '2018-01-09T12:30:00',
    allDay: false // will make the time show
  }
];

$('#calendar').fullCalendar();

//Simulate an async call
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', myEvents);
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.8.0/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.8.0/fullcalendar.js"></script>


<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Comment: THANK YOU for the help unfortunately I get the same result - no events render using the data I built however if i use the data you crafted or if I simply take the data I generate and copy and paste it from the alert window it works perfectly. Completely stumped, can you offer any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because I was using momentJS objects for the event time ('start'/'end') and it has to be convert it to ISO string (exemple: `moment(startTime).toISOString()`) to make it work.

Hope it helps